# Add a mouseover and pressed/clicked effect on element in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-store, uwp-xaml

I'm currently working on an app to show all parking spaces in Kortrijk (a city in Belgium). This is how it looks at the moment:

## Design

[image: Parking spots app]

My question is: how can I for example change the color of the element on mouseover or on click. I want to accomplish this in the XAML and this is the code that I have now.

## Code

#### MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="ParkingSpots.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ParkingSpots"
xmlns:model="using:ParkingSpots.model"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <model:ParkingSpot x:Key="spots"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Style="{StaticResource mainGrid}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Parking spots in Kortrijk"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource spots}, Path=ParkingSpots}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParkingSpotTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ParkingSpotsTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

#### style.xaml (external xaml file)

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ParkingSpots.style"
xmlns:conv="using:ParkingSpots.converter">

<conv:StreetConverter x:Key="StreetConv" />

<Color x:Key="Color1">#FFB3B6F2</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color2">#FF5A58D9</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color3">#FFF2F2F2</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color1Brush" Color="{StaticResource Color1}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color2Brush" Color="{StaticResource Color2}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color3Brush" Color="{StaticResource Color3}" />

<Style x:Name="mainGrid" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Color1Brush}"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ParkingSpotTemplate">
    <ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Color3Brush}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ListViewItem.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ParkingSpotInfo" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Street, Converter={StaticResource StreetConv}}"/>
    </ListViewItem>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ParkingSpotsTemplate">
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="wrapGrid"></VariableSizedWrapGrid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

I tried something with style.triggers but this is only possible in WPF apps and not in UWP apps. I've also read a lot of things about visualstates but I don't know how to use it and if this is the best way to do such effects.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using a ListView to display this data instead of an ItemsControl (unless you have a good reason for doing so). ListView extends from ItemsControl and adds to it lots of useful features, such as:

- Single/multiple item selection.
- ItemClick event.
- Each item container is a ListViewItem control which has its own features like visual states and a checkbox, and the presentation of the ListViewItem is managed by a ListViewItemPresenter which can deliver these features in an optimized manner.
- Built-in ScrollViewer.
- Data and UI virtualization. UI virtualization is a big advantage when you have 100s of items.
- Accessible. Supports tab-focusing.
- Probably more...

ItemsControl isn't typically used for situations where you want to interact with the items (by click/tap, for example).

ListView by default has its own style which can be easily overridden to match what you have already.

If you only want to style the ListViewItem background/foreground for each visual state, then you can override these styles:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <!--
            These resources are applied to this ListView only. Put in a
            higher scope (page or app) depending on what you want it to affect.
        -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver" Color="Violet"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Yellow"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="LimeGreen"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Blue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPressed" Color="Cyan"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="Orange"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this should be a ListView instead of an ItemsControl?

Comment: Is it still possible to use a VariableSizedWrapGrid with the ListView. I need this to show them next to each other on larger screens.

Comment: I've updated the code in my question. I did not yet implemented the hover and click effect but whit this code my app crashes.

Comment: You'll need to use [ItemsWrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298849) instead of VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Comment: You might even want to use GridView instead of ListView if your items will be predominantly displayed in a grid fashion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127270/discussion-between-gillis-werrebrouck-and-decade-moon).